# CakePHP link on Paginator ellipsis

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, ellipsis

I want to put a link on an ellipsis in the Paginator. When the pagination has 2 ellipsis's the ellipsis must have different link.

My code is:

```
echo $this->paginator->numbers(array(
        'tag'          => 'li',
        'separator'    => '',
        'currentTag'   => 'a',
        'currentClass' => 'active',
        'modulus'      => 2,
        'first'        => 1,
        'last'         => 1,
        'ellipsis'     => "<li><a href='#' class='hellip'>...</a></li>"
    ));
```

So the result I want to create is:

1 ...(link) 6 7 8 ...(link) 12

Comment: What happened when you use that code?

Comment: It does give me the ellipsis on both sides, but I can't edit them seperatily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the Paginator doesn't support what you want it to do and so your only option is to modify the CakePHP source code. Specifically [PaginatorHelper.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.7/lib/Cake/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php)

First thing you'll need to do is modify the `$defaults` variable on line 720, and add `leftEllipsis` and `rightEllipsis` fields. This means that we can maintain consistent behavior when we don't set these fields in the `$options` variable.

```
$defaults = array('tag' => 'span', 'before' => null, 'after' => null,
'model' => $this->defaultModel(), 'class' => null,'modulus' => '8',
'separator' => ' | ', 'first' => null, 'last' => null, 'ellipsis' => '...',
'currentClass' => 'current', 'currentTag' => null, 'leftEllipsis' => null,
'rightEllipsis' => null);
```

Probably should unset our two new fields too (lines 735 - 738):

```
unset($options['tag'], $options['before'], $options['after'], $options['model'],
$options['modulus'], $options['separator'], $options['first'], $options['last'],
$options['ellipsis'], $options['class'], $options['currentClass'], $options['currentTag'],
$options['leftEllipsis'], $options['rightEllipsis']
    );
```

The next bit is a tad tricky because it would be nice to be able to specify one of the ellipsis without the other, and in the absence of either, fallback onto whatever the original `ellipsis` field was set to. But the developers have used the magical `extract` and `compact` functions coupled with the `first(...)` and `last(...)` functions depending on certain fields being set in the `$options` parameter.

After line 756 insert the following code to default the `$leftEllipsis` to whatever `$ellipsis` is set to:

```
if(isempty($leftEllipsis)) {
  $leftEllipsis = $ellipsis;
}
```

Next we need to modify what gets passed as the `$options` parameter to the `first(...)` function on lines 758 - 761.

```
if ($offset < $start - 1) {
  $out .= $this->first($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'class') + array('ellipsis' => $leftEllipsis));
} else {
  $out .= $this->first($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'class') + array('after' => $separator, 'ellipsis' => $leftEllipsis));
}
```

You can use this pattern to attack the right ellipsis too.

The proper way to do this is to fork the project on GitHub, make the changes to your version of the code base and create a pull request so you give the developers a chance to integrate your feature into the mainline. This way everyone can benefit from your work!

Good luck!

Comment: Where did you get the offset variable?

Comment: `$offset` is defined on line 756 on the original source code that I referenced at the beginning of my answer. You may wish to check the version of CakePHP you're using because my answer is geared towards version 2.5.7